# Definition of simple measure

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show that $f:X\to \mathbb{C}$ is simple iff $f$ is measurable and the range of $f$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I understand the first direction ($\implies$) where I know that characteristic functions of measurable sets are measurable, and a constant times a measurable function is measurable, and then I can add multiple measurable functions to get a measurable function which shows that $f$ is measurable.

Now similarly, I can observe that the range of the function takes on finite values of the complex numbers (though would I need more justification here?)

Now the second direction ($\impliedby$) is where my confusion arises. I assume that $f$ is measurable and the range of $f$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{C}$. How would I show that $E_j$ is a measurable set? I thought that each set $\{z_j\}$ is closed as it is a singleton so I feel that I cannot use the measurability of $f$ to show that $f^{-1}(\{z_j\})=E_j\in \mathcal{M}$.

[image]

Comment: Title should say "simple function not "simple measure".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is measurable and $y \in Range(f)$ then $E_y=f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is a measurable set (since it is the preimage of the measurable set $\{y\}$). Measurability does not require openness or closeness of the set (measurability is way weaker than continuity).

$$\{y\} = \cap_{\varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}} B_{\varepsilon}(y)$$
is a countable intersection of open sets and is therefore measurable.

Comment: Why is it that $\{y\}$ is measurable?

Comment: Closed sets are measurable since they are the complement of open sets. The sigma algebra is closed under complements, so it contains all closed sets (and open sets and much more).

Comment: The key here is that $\mathbb{C}$ is a metrizable measure space with a Borel sigma algebra (From my bit of research right now on singletons being measurable) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384150/are-infinite-dimensional-singletons-measurable